# child pid exit signal Segmentation fault (11) after upgrade to PHP 5.3.19

Tags: php, yum

I've upgrade PHP on my centos machine to 5.3.19 last night and now some parts of my application (especially when submitting a form that runs a number of larger queries) I get the following error in /var/log/httpd/error_log

```
child pid xxxx exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

In Chrome, it shows the following 
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this or maybe even how to revert to a previous version of PHP by using YUM.

UPDATE: the problem is described here, but I'm not sure about the solution. We load up a rather large SQL file and run each query inside of it step by step, that's the "recursion" part if I'm not mistaken: http://bitdepth.thomasrutter.com/2010/05/16/php-recursion-causes-segmentation-fault/

Comment: Why not try upgrading to 5.4, maybe that will solve the problem...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the recursion is a problem here. Your scripts would most likely have caused the same problems prior the update if so.

One of the php modules might be not up-to-date. Did you manually compile or install modules using pear before the update? If so those module have to be recompiled against the new php version.

To find out which modules might be compiled manually, compare the ini files in your `/etc/php.d` folder with the output of

```
yum list installed | grep "php"
```

This lists all regularly installed php related packages which should not cause a problem after the update

To find out which packages you might have installed using pecl you can also run this:

```
# pecl list
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package   Version State
memcached 2.1.0   stable
ssh2      0.11.3  beta
```

If you get a list like this update those modules using

```
 pecl upgrade-all
```

If you have modules active which are not installed with pecl and not installed with yum those modules are compiled manually and need to be recompiled

In this case you can follow the steps of the approved answer here
https://serverfault.com/questions/261268/how-to-build-missing-php-5-3-extensions-on-centos-5-6